# Does the truth that Naofumi did nothing to Myne ever come out?

Tags: the-rising-of-the-shield-hero

Does the truth ever come out that Naofumi did nothing to Myne, in The Rising o the Shield Hero ?

I don't care for spoilers, it would be really good to know if the truth ever come out or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Myne's wikia page](https://shield-hero.fandom.com/wiki/Malty_S_Melromarc#Volume_4), **the truth does indeed come out, and she was punished for it**. In **Volume 4**,

> [The Queen](https://shield-hero.fandom.com/wiki/Mirelia_Q_Melromarc) exposed all of Malty's crimes, stripped her of royalty and, as an extra punishment, renamed her "Bitch" for her false rape claims, on Naofumi's suggestion. Alternative acceptable names by royal decree include "Whore" and "Slut".

This does not, however, change her in any way as it was also noted that she still harbors ill feelings towards Naofumi and considers everything that happened to her 'entirely his fault.'